# What is the modern @font-face declaration?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

Over the years, I've used the following font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'museo_sans_rounded';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src:  url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.eot');
  src:  url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/museo/museosansrounded-300-webfont.svg#museo_sans_rounded300') format('svg');
}
```

Now I just need to support IE11 and all the modern browsers.  Can this declaration be simplified?

Comment: there's no modern @font-face declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this article on [embedding custom fonts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) using `@font-face`:

> The @font-face rule allows custom fonts to be loaded on a webpage. Once added to a stylesheet, the rule instructs the browser to download the font from where it is hosted, then display it as specified in the CSS.

There are various different levels of browser support for different fonts. The trend seems to be that you can get away with offering WOFF and WOFF2, but this is their recommendation for "deepest possible browser support":

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

For IE11:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: So which declaration satisfies IE11?

Comment: What do you mean by `Legacy iOS`?  To to which versions?

Comment: added IE11 (which is also described in the article I linked to). By Legacy IoS, I assume they mean "everything that is not specifically listed by version number in the article" -- but presumably not really really old browsers.

Comment: @AngryHacker: Safari requires SVG for webfonts up to and including iOS 4.1, which is several years older than IE11. You can safely leave SVG fonts out for that reason. The second example provided here is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
.eot ==> for IE9 Compat Modes
.eot?#iefix ==> for IE6-IE8 
.woff2 ==> for super Modern browser like Chrome, Firefox...
.woff ==> for pretty Modern.. so to speak
.ttf ==> specially for Safari, Android, iOS
.svg#svgFontName ==> just for Legacy iOS
```

Comment: pls add some explanation code only answers are bit confusing to others

Comment: Which of these statements will satisfy IE11 requirement?  And when you say Legacy iOS - up to which version?  If I support iOS 10 and up, can I get away with .ttf?

Comment: Dear @RamGhadiyaram 

here is the full list of font type extension: 
https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/font

Comment: Cuong : I mean to say even if it is external content. you have to explain in answer. links may be dead after some time.